# extract single variable from JSON array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, var

I hope my question is not as stupid as I think it is...

I want to extract (the value of) a single variable from an JSONarray. I have this jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#gb_form").submit(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $.post("guestbook1.php",$("#gb_form").serialize(),function(data){
        if(data !== false) {
            var entry = data;
            $('.entries').prepend(entry);           
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

the content of data looks like this ("MyMessage" and "MyName" are values written in a simple form from user):

> [{"message":"MyMessage","name":"MyName"}]

the var "entry" should give (more or less) following output at the end:

"Send from -MyName-  : -MyMessage-"

I'm not able to extract the single array values from data. I tried things like that:

```
var message = data['message'];
var name = data['name']
var entry = "Send from" + name + ":" +message;
```

but that gives "Send from undefined: undefined"

Hope you can help me with that.

Comment: Should it not be `data[0]->message`?

Comment: @LuckySoni You mean `data[0].message`?

Comment: @Scimonster lol yes, doing a lot of PHP these days :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can do like this to get first item of array:

```
var msg = "Send from"+data[0].name + " "+data[0].message;

console.log(msg );
```

[**SAMPLE FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/nhtVy/)

## UPDATE:

as you are using **$.post** you will need to explicitly parse response as json:

```
$.post("guestbook1.php",$("#gb_form").serialize(),function(data){
        var response = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

        var msg = "Send from"+response [0].name + " "+response [0].message;
        console.log(msg );

      });
```

Comment: if json is returned as response it will work and OP has shown that it is returing json so it should work

Comment: `$.post()` won't parse the JSON automatically. You need to pass it a `"json"` parameter, which is not in the code in the question, so `data` is an unparsed string.

Comment: Finaly! Thank you both very much. parse was the missing part.

Answer (score 0):

To access an array you use the `[]` notation

To access an object you use the `.` notation

So in case of `[{JSON_OBJECT}, {JSON_OBJECT}]`

if we have the above array of JSON objects in a variable called `data`, you will first need to access a particular Json Object in the array:

```
data[0] // First JSON Object in array
data[1] // Second JSON Object in array.. and so on
```

Then to access the properties of the JSON Object we need to do it like so:

```
data[0].name // Will return the value of the `name` property from the first JSON Object inside the data array
data[1].name // Will return the value of the `name` property from the second JSON Object inside the data array
```